# Try catch around a toggle method of jquery-ui not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, try-catch

I have a page in which a button click invokes the following JavaScript code. The page uses jquery and jquery-ui for animation. This code uses the `toggle` method of jquery-ui and not a similar method of jquery.

I am deliberately passing an incorrect value for the first parameter of `animation effect` to check if the catch block works as expected.

The first time the button is clicked and this code is invoked, an exception is thrown and catch block is reached. But when I invoke the same code a second time by clicking the button again, then the catch block is never reached, instead control goes directly to the first line after catch block even though the first parameter is still invalid.

**Question** : Why is an invalid animation effect parameter not throwing an exception when called a second time, but only throwing it the first time its called?

```
var emt = $("#cDiv"); 
try {
    emt.hide();
    emt.toggle("xyz", {
        easing: "swing"
    }, 1000, function() {
        animationCompleted = true;
        startPolling();
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

I have a added a code sample on jsfiddle to demonstrate my problem. The sample is at this url: http://jsfiddle.net/sun21170/rm580npe/4/

In this code sample, if a valid animation effect is selected from the drop-down then the `Custom Div` animates as expected, but if `xyz` is selected as the animation effect, then we get an error which can be seen in the errors div. However, the error does not show up repeatedly on clicking `Animate Custom Div` button while `xyz` is the selected animation effect.

Comment: `Why is an invalid animation effect parameter not throwing an exception when called a second time` - short answer, because asynchrony

Comment: @JaromandaX, So is there any way to capture the error message when invoked a second time? Hope there was an error callback like in jquery ajax.

Comment: actually, I may have jumped the gun. I thought you were trying to catch an error in the callback, though it seems you were not

Comment: Its really strange that it throws an error only the first time.

Comment: what is strange is that you are getting into the catch block the first time. What is the error you are getting

Comment: I get this error the first time that the error is caught by the catch block: `m.easing[this.easing] is not a function`

Comment: The first parameter should be the name of animation effect like `slide` or `fade` or `pulsate` or `drop` etc. So, when I pass a non-existent value for the effect, it throws an error but only the first time.

Comment: so it complains about the easing, not the animation effect. As I said, i tried what you are doing and don't get an error thrown at all, if the method is not known, it seems to be ignored rather than producing an error. Something else seems to be going on in your code

Comment: @JaromandaX, I have added a demo of my problem on jsfiddle at : http://jsfiddle.net/sun21170/rm580npe/1/.  You can easily reproduce my problem there using instructions under `UPDATE 1` in my post.

Comment: @JaromandaX, A more detailed jsfiddle  can also be seen at: http://jsfiddle.net/sun21170/rm580npe/4/